# Delete a user from mediawiki in the SQL db

Tags: sql, mediawiki

Since I implemented active directory into my mediawiki, I have a certain problem that I got a user now which is actually not there. I means once I click or hover over the user it tells me:

> User is not registred

I tried to merge it with the userMerge extension, but the user doesn't exist obviously, but he is in the userlist. Makes no sense to me at all.

So I know you shouldn't delete a user from an SQL table; I need to  because our internal wiki should not have any local users any more. Also here I can't really find any good explanations of where I can find the user tables in the phpmyadmin panel. I would appreciate the help.

Mediawiki got installed with XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Mediawiki doesn't really support deleting users. The commonly accepted practice is to ban/block misbehaving users. In recent years, large-scale spambots have been a problem resulting in a lot of garbage wiki accounts, so it looks like there are some solutions. Here's the extension that looked the most relevant:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserMerge
This lets you merge a user's contributions in with another user's, and then delete one of the user accounts.